# How to access dictionary values in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How to access the dictionary value in django template?   I want to get the value of the variable `a` actually

```
class Emp(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

  def get_names(self):
    names = {}
    names_desc = {}
    nbl = {}
    names.update({'a' : 1})
    names_desc.update({'b' : 2})
    nbl.update({'names' : names,'names_desc' : names_desc})
    return nbl
```

emp is my object that i am passing to the template
Is it {{emp.get_names}}?? or {{emp.get_names.names.a}}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{{ emp.get_names.names.a }} will get you 1 in the template

{{ emp.get_names.names }} will get you {'A':1} in the template

{{ emp.get_names }} will get you {'names_desc': {'b': 2}, 'names': {'a': 1}} in the template
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{emp.get_names}}`

This will return the whole 'nb1' dict.

You should go with the second one.